# Why are slopes of lines compared for the below solution?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Below is the solution for ,https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stars

```
for (int iStar1 = 0; iStar1 < n; iStar1++)
{
    for (int iStar2 = iStar1 + 1; iStar2 < n; iStar2++)
    {
        int sum1 = 0;
        for (int iStar3 = 0; iStar3 < n; iStar3++)
        {
            long line1 = (long)(stars[iStar3].y - stars[iStar1].y) * (stars[iStar2].x - stars[iStar1].x);
            long line2 = (long)(stars[iStar3].x - stars[iStar1].x) * (stars[iStar2].y - stars[iStar1].y);
            if ((iStar3 != iStar1) && (iStar3 != iStar2) && (line1 < line2))
            {
                sum1 += stars[iStar3].v;
            }
        }
        int sum2 = sum1 + stars[iStar1].v + stars[iStar2].v;

        if (sum1 > totalV - sum1)
        {
            sum1 = totalV - sum1;
        }
        if (sum2 > totalV - sum2)
        {
            sum2 = totalV - sum2;
        }

        if (sum1 > bestSum)
        {
            bestSum = sum1;
        }
        if (sum2 > bestSum)
        {
            bestSum = sum2;
        }
    }
}
```

Why are the slopes of lines formed by existing points compared to get the separating line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider pushing the optimal separating line you will always be able to push it until it hits a point, and then rotate it until it hits another point.

The score for this adjusted line will be the same as the original score, so you only need to consider such adjusted lines that go through two of the original points.

The reason for doing this is because this greatly reduces the number of possible separating lines that have to be considered.